# How to enable custom html helper extension method to all views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an issue on custom html helper method. I have added two custom html helper method. First method is MyTextBox and second one is MySelectBox Method which is extention to the HtmlHelper class.The following code is working fine.

**C# :**

```
namespace MyHtmlHelper
{
   public static class HtmlHelperClass
   {
      public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBox(string fieldName)
      {
        return new MvcHtmlString("<input type=\"text\" name=\"" + fieldName + "\"></input>");
      }
    }
}

    namespace MyHtmlHelper
    {
        public static class HtmlHelperExtension
        {
            public static MvcHtmlString MySelectBox(this HtmlHelper helper, string text)
            {
                return new MvcHtmlString("<select ><option>" + text + "</option></select>");
            }
        }
    }
```

**view:**

```
@using MyHtmlHelper

<div>
    @MyHtmlHelper.HtmlHelperClass.MyTextBox("test")
    @Html.MySelectBox("Test")
</div>
```

I want this html helper method for all views in my application.so i removed MyHtmlHelper namespace from view and added in web.cong as follows

**Web.config :**

```
  <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        <add namespace="MyHtmlHelper"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

**My Problem is :**  **MyTextBox helper method working fine** but **html extension method (MySelectBox) is not working**.Anyone please help me ,what mistake i have done or how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a another webconfig in the view folder. You have to use this.

[image]